# Electron react boilerplate problem with APIs

Tags: electron, mapbox-gl-js, electron-react-boilerplate

I am using a static map API on Electron-react boilerplate project. The map shown in development mode only, but when I am packing the project as an app (.exe/.msi) the map api will not shows. I have tried to change the API but I get the same problem.

I followed the exact following this [repository](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate)

I have the map API in this path `app/components` .

Here is the part when I have added the map code

```
import DeckGL from '@deck.gl/react';
import { StaticMap } from 'react-map-gl';
```

```
        <DeckGL initialViewState={viewState} layers={layers} controller>
          <StaticMap
            mapboxApiAccessToken={MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN}
            mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9"
            width={10}
            height={10}
          />
        </DeckGL>
```

Comment: How you get this `MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN`

Comment: You are using env?

Comment: If so, I think you should make sure if this will be replaced properly while building

Comment: Nah, I am using it as a variable. const MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN = 'pk....'